# pfSense Mutli-WAN IP on single interface not achieved so far

Tags: pfsense

I have 5 public IP from ISP and want to utilize all IPs on single WAN interface.

My PFSENSE router box has 2 interfaces as follow :

em0  --- >  WAN Interface (172.27.0.1)
em1  --- >  LAN Interface ( 192.168.1.1/24)

Now I want to configure multiple public IP's to wan interface to use port forwarding from my LAN to Public IP.

Example : webserver 1 --- >  Public IP 1
          webserver 2 ---->  public IP 2
          webserver 3 ---->  public IP 3.

Anyone suggest me get achieve this to my router ?

1 to 1 NAT solution wont work for me, because the way it works under DHCP and need unique MAC address in order receive IP address from the ISP .

If expertise have solutions for this ?? or suggest which is the best way ??

or can I do virtualization with VMware,Xen,Virtualbox ?

Answer (score 0):

This video shows how to do it in the GUI.  Too bad they don't write it up as well.

[Youtube demo multi WAN IP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrBr0N0WrTY)

Comment: Thanks for your empty. As earlier I told you, This video won't help because they use 1:1 nat to map public IP.

Comment: The problem is I need a kind of virtual NIC with different mac address so that way I can get IP from the DHCP.